# Linux partition types

Tags: linux, filesystems, partition

I'm trying to dual boot Windows and Arch Linux on my laptop while following a tutorial.

I am instructed to make:

```
/boot 200 MB ext2

swap 8 GB swap

/ 250 GB ext4
```

I used `fdisk` to make a partition table. These three end up as: sda6, sda7, sda8 respectively.

After that, I try to change the partition type and am successful with the swap (sda7) but I can't find ext2 or ext4 for the partition types. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5):

The partition type is different from a filesystem type.  The partition type to choose is `Linux`.

`ext2` and `ext4` are filesystems.  These are determined by the formatting used ***after*** the partitions are created.

Comment: The partition type would be linux filesystem. Should I also chance sda7 from swap to linux filesystem?

Comment: No.  The swap partition type is well defined for it.  Other types would work but may not be automatically detected.

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure about the significance of partition types, but they seem to be a way of letting the OS know what partitions it can touch.

You have to make a filesystem in the specific partition. For swap you use `mkswap`, for ext2 `mkfs.ext2`, for ext4 `mkfs.ext4` and so on.

The partition type is changed using `fdisk`.

As root or sudo type `fdisk /dev/sda`

On the prompt, type `t` for "Toggle Partition Type". It will ask you for a partition number.

```
Partition number (1-3, default 3):
```

(If you do not know the partition number, type `p` to print the partition table). Type the partition number. Next, it prints

```
Partition type (type L to list all types): L
```

This gives you a listing of known partition types. The important ones are:

```
7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT - For Windows systems
f  W95 Ext'd (LBA) - For an extended partition (I prefer f instead of 5 b'cos of LBA)
```

The Linux ones are:

```
82 Linux swap
83 Linux
8e Linux LVM
fd Linux raid auto
```

For your use case, you need `83`.

Note: This is for MBR partition table. If using GPT, the partition type is 16-bits longs and AFAIK, is prepended with a 00. Someone can correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: This tells OP how to get the partition type using fdisk.

Comment: That is not the question.  He obviously knows how to set it since he did it for swap and just wants to know which one to select.

Comment: Does the answer not tell him which one to select? `83` if not using LVM (which he is not).

Comment: I wanted to know how to make a partition ext2 or ext4 build basically gave me a general idea of how it worked and answered what was bothering me